# Передать в функцию множество значений php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите каким образом передать в функцию множество значений, примерно таким образом:

```
function name($val) { ... }
// а здесь уже так сделать
name(1, 2, 3, 4, ...);
```

И при этом чтоб не было ошибок.
А внутри чтоб это все можно было обработать (каждое значение).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function name() { 
   //получаем массив аргументов функции 
   $arguments = func_get_args();
}

name(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 2):

А вариант, где $val=[1,2,3...], и соответственно name([1,2,3...]) не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

А если вдруг у вас php5.6

```
function name(...$vars) { 
    print_r($vars);
}

name(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

представим, что мы наплодили 20 глобальных переменных и их надо передавать в
какие-то функции, как это сделать не забивая код функции именами переменных

быстрее всего это будет работать так ...
создаем класс с именами глобальных переменных

```
class g {  
    public static $arrElements;
    public static $arrSectionns;
    public static $arrProperties;
}

// заполняем данными
g::$arrElements = getElements($block);
g::$arrSections = getSections($block);
g::$arrProperties = getProperties($block);

function foo() {
    // используем внутри функции g::$**** сколько угодно
}
```